# How to disable Turborepo "Update available" message?

Tags: typescript, monorepo, turborepo

I get these message when I use Turborepo :

╭───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮

│                                                                       │

│                  Update available v1.10.1 ≫ v1.10.3                   │

│    Changelog: https://github.com/vercel/turbo/releases/tag/v1.10.3    │

│               Run "npx @turbo/codemod update" to update               │

│                                                                       │

│     Follow @turborepo for updates: https://twitter.com/turborepo      │

╰───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯

They take 8 lines of console and are very obstrusive

How to disable them ? Also I don t want turborepo to be checking at all for updates, how can I disable that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable the message by setting `NO_UPDATE_NOTIFIER` or `TURBO_NO_UPDATE_NOTIFIER` environment variables.

Sample `package.json`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "TURBO_NO_UPDATE_NOTIFIER=true turbo run build",
  }
}
```

[GitHub source](https://github.com/vercel/turbo/blob/c78593b649cab2def7cdbac55d85139188598604/crates/turborepo-updater/src/lib.rs#L21C66-L21C90)